# Retrieving final destination multi-redirect HTML using Python Requests

Tags: python, redirect, python-requests

I am trying to analyze the HTML from the final redirect of this URL: https://findtheinmate.com/mills.

When I try to use the following code block, I see the intermediate page (`"Loading ... Please Wait"`) in the response text:

```
import requests
u = "https://findtheinmate.com/mills"
r = requests.get(u, allow_redirects=True)
```

It appears there's a JavaScript function being called on one of the pages (`loadTheData();`), and I'm unclear if there's a way to work around this and wait for the final page resolution *without using Selenium or a driver tool*. The final destination URL is dynamic, but something like: http://findtheinmate.com/gsapdfs/169600227515429.VERIFY.20361.56675413.html.